# How to test a service that get data from a database using JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

i write a java service that get a data from database  :

```
public List<Operation> listOperations(String code){

//some business logic...

}
```

i tested the service manually with the a code from my database `listOperations("CEA1");` and it works fine and it return to me a List with 3 Operation Objects(the same result in my database).

now i want to test my service using Mockito and JUnit but i'm beginner in unit testing (but i know what is the concepts of unit testing,mocking...),

this is my uncompleted test class :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyserviceTest {

    @Mock
    private OperationRepository  operationRepositoryMock;


    @InjectMocks
    private BanqueServiceImpl banqueServiceImpl;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testListOfOperation(){

        String code = "CEA1";

        //to check if my service is working good ,the code 'CEA1' should return a list with 3 Operation object
        when(operationRepositoryMock.listOperations(code)). // i dont know how to mock the result


boolean result = banqueServiceImpl.listOperations(code); // i don't know how to assert that the service return a list that contains 3 Operation object

        //assertTrue(result);
    }
```

please can anyone help me to complete my test code , note i'm working in a spring boot project.

Regards!

Comment: If your service returns list, then why do you assing a result to the `boolean`?

Comment: Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: @JakubCh. it just a small mistake because a copy§past the snippet of code

Comment: Can you explain to us the functionality that is performed by the `listOperations` method? Having an understanding of what the method does should help us identify how to test it. For instance, if it's simply calling a data access method and returning the data as retrieved from the database, then, you shouldn't bother unit testing it at all!

Comment: Before you think about HOW to write the test, spend some time and think about WHAT the test cases should be attempting to validate

Comment: @Ben thank you so much for your time,you are right i should specify the the test case now i'm focusing in list of with 3 object as a result and maybe this wrong , and it should be the service should return a list of Operation object  , is it right ? as i say i'm beginner in unit testing , regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prepare your list of Operation

```
Operation sampleOperation = new Operation();
List<Operation> operationList = new ArrayList<Operation>();
operationList.add(sampleOperation);
```

now use mockito to return  `operationList` when `listOperations()` method is called

```
when(operationRepositoryMock.listOperations(eq("CEA1"))).thenReturn(operationList);
```

Now you can use assertion to verify size of list or verify content of list

```
assertThat("size is equal to 1", banqueServiceImpl.listOperations(code).size(), is(1));
```

Comment: @want2leam thank you for your time and your  response ,but i still have one question, i know that the service should return a list with 3 objects so i try with :  `assertThat("size is equal to 3", banqueServiceImpl.listOperations(code).size(), is(3));` but the test is failure with the following message : Expected is <3> but was <1>is that mean i should add 3 objects to my prepared list "operationList"? if yes i'm wondering i have a service that return a list with 200 objects should i prepare a list with this number of objects(its very difficult)? please clarify to me this point . best Regards

Comment: If you asserting with 3, yes you have to prepare 3 object and add to list. You should know operationRepositoryMock is a mock not a real object and here you are testing the behavior of the method so you don't have to prepare 200 objects and add to list.

Comment: thank you so much, i got the idea  i was confusing between behavior and results.. , you are the best

Comment: So if you think this is right answer, you might mark my answer as correct answer and upvote. Thanks